# How do I buffer Flux of GroupedFlux?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor

I am trying to implement a buffering process in Reactor on a Flux of Fluxes. Each emission on the inner fluxes is grouped by some attribute and emitted after the Buffer duration has expired.

The following test (simplified to expose problem) illustrates the desired behavior:

```
private static final long STEP_MILLIS = 50;

private static final Duration BUFFER_DURATION = Duration.ofMillis(STEP_MILLIS * 4);

@Test
public void testBuffer() throws Exception {
    List<List<String>> buffers = new ArrayList<>();

    UnicastProcessor<String> queue = UnicastProcessor.create();
    FluxSink<String> sink = queue.sink();

    Flux<Flux<String>> fluxOfFlux = queue.map(Flux::just);

    // Buffering
    fluxOfFlux.flatMap(Function.identity())
        .transform(this::buffer)
        .subscribe(buffers::add);

    sink.next("TEST 1");

    Thread.sleep(BUFFER_DURATION.toMillis() - STEP_MILLIS);  // One "step" before Buffer should close

    assertTrue(buffers.isEmpty());

    sink.next("TEST 2");

    assertTrue(buffers.isEmpty());

    Thread.sleep(STEP_MILLIS * 2); // One "step" after Buffer should close

    assertEquals(1, buffers.size());
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("TEST 1", "TEST 2"), buffers.get(0));
}

public Flux<List<String>> buffer(Flux<String> publisher) {
    return publisher
        .groupBy(Object::getClass)
        .map(groupFlux -> groupFlux.take(BUFFER_DURATION).collectList())
        .flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

This test works as written; The problem arises when I try to combine the "flatMap" and "transform" operations in to one operation:

```
    // Buffering
    fluxOfFlux.flatMap(flux -> flux.transform(this::buffer))
        .subscribe(buffers::add);
```

The test then fails as every item put in to the queue is immediately emitted as a singleton "buffer".

This is undesirable because having to flatMap before buffering removes the ability to parallelize processing of the inner Fluxes.

This is written with Reactor, but should map 1-to-1 with RxJava using Observable and methods of similar names.

Anybody have thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still starting with reactor but your code doesn't seems non-side-effect free. Keep state (in your case using the List<> buffers) may lead to nasty bugs in the future.

You can achieve the same just using immutables as you can see bellow

```
List<String> tests = Arrays.asList("TEST 1", "TEST 2", "TEST 3", "INTEGRATION 1", "INTEGRATION 2")

@Test
public void test() {
    Flux<List<String>> bufferedFlux = Flux.fromIterable(tests).buffer(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> bufferedFlux)
            .expectNext(tests)
            .verifyComplete();
}

@Test
public void group() {
    Flux<GroupedFlux<String, String>> flux = Flux
            .fromIterable(tests)
            .groupBy(test -> test.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""));

    StepVerifier.create(flux)
            .expectNextMatches(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux.key().equals("TEST"))
            .expectNextMatches(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux.key().equals("INTEGRATION"))
            .verifyComplete();


    Flux<String> sum = flux
            .flatMap(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux
                    .map(test -> test.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""))
                    .map(Integer::valueOf)
                    .reduce((t1, t2) -> t1 + t2)
                    .map(total -> groupedFlux.key() + " TOTAL: " + total)
            ).sort();

    StepVerifier.create(sum)
            .expectNext("INTEGRATION TOTAL: 3")
            .expectNext("TEST TOTAL: 6")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem with the combined approach: The jist is that what I wanted to accomplish is not possible with the example data as written.

Using the condensed approach, what actually ends up getting buffered is each inner Flux on its own. Since each of those Fluxes completes after emitting its singleton, this causes the enclosing buffer to complete and be emitted as well. This led to the realization of what was going wrong in my application.

I had to address this flaw in my application's design by changing how I was generating the inner Fluxes further upstream to first `concatMap` and *then* group in to inner Fluxes.